# Rotating datalabel in core plot line chart

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

As of now, the line chart I've drawn with Core plot looks like this :

[image]

As you can see, some of the labels of the plots are overlapping. I thought it would be good if I can display them vertically (just like the labels in the x-axes have been displayed). How do I do it?

This is my code snippet for dataLabelForPlot:

```
-(CPTLayer *) dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

        NSString *currentlabel = [lineChartPlotXLabel objectAtIndex:index];
        CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle       = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
        textStyle.color = [CPTColor darkGrayColor];
        textStyle.fontSize  = 10.0f;
        textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica";
        CPTLayer *layer = [[CPTLayer alloc] 
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 70.0, 20.0)];
        CPTTextLayer *newLayer = nil;
        newLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:currentlabel style:textStyle];
        [layer addSublayer:newLayer];
        return layer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `labelRotation` on the plot.